# List comprehension on Python dict doesn't perform well

Tags: python

I have the following loop:

```
for row in rows:
    print row.value('customer', 'name')
#   print [customer for customer in customers if customer['name'] == row.value('customer', 'name')]
```

When I uncomment the second `print`, the loop runs much more slowly. Is there a way I can write this to make it perform faster?

My overall problem is that I used to do a separate SQL query for each `row` to get the matching customer for that row. Now I'm trying to grab all the customers up front in an effort to improve performance.

One row of `customers` looks like this, FYI:

```
{'name': u'JOHN SMITH', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 14, 49, 57), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 3, 16, 41, 1), 'customer_number': u'C102340', 'phone': u'', 'social_security_number': u'2352352', 'do_not_mail': None, 'id': 4154L, 'deceased': None}
```

Comment: Is any name unique within you `customers`?

Comment: No, the names are not necessarily unique. Customer uniqueness is determined by name, customer number, SSN and phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It runs much more slowly" because you are looking at the entire customer-list for each row.

Either make a dictionary of customers and use a lookup:

```
customerIndex = { customer['name']:customer for customer in customers }
for row in rows:
    name = row.value('customer','name')
    print name, customerIndex[name]
```

or modify your SQL query to return relevant customer information with each row (something like `row INNER JOIN customer ON row.customer_id==customer.id`)

Comment: Note that in older versions of python, `{ a:b for c in d }` won't work, you'll need to use `dict((a,b) for c in d)` instead.

Comment: Does an index work for multiple attributes? I'll ultimately need to find customers based not solely on name but by name, customer number, SSN and phone number.

Comment: @Jason: you can do that by wrapping the multiple attributes in a tuple, however this sounds like something that would be much more efficiently handled in SQL *if* you do it right (in about 98% of cases, sub-selects are *not* doing it right).

Comment: Yeah, I should probably actually do that in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not clear what exactly 'customers' is. If you make a dict from name to row and say customers.get(row.value('customer', 'name')) it should do a very fast lookup for each customer.
2. Don't store social security numbers unless you absolutely have to. I know this is unrelated, but it is really easy to take the last 4-5 digits of a SSN and recover the full SSN if you know where the person lives and how old they are.